# Optimizing Python Image Downloads for 30MB Images within Milliseconds

Tags: python, image-processing, optimization, python-requests, download

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a Python script to download 30MB size images efficiently. I've been using the requests library, but the download time is not meeting my expectations. Below is a simplified version of my code:
import requests

```
def download_image(url, save_folder):
    # Your download logic here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_urls = ["https://example.com/image1.jpg", "https://example.com/image2.jpg"]
    save_folder = "downloaded_images"

    for url in image_urls:
        download_image(url, save_folder)
```

I am aiming to achieve faster downloads within a millisecond timeframe. I understand that network conditions and server response times are limiting factors, but I'm looking for optimizations within the script itself. Is there a more efficient library or approach to achieve faster downloads?

Specifically, I'm interested in:

Any improvements to my current code.
Alternative libraries or methods that are known for faster image downloads.
General tips or best practices for optimizing image download processes in Python.
I'm open to any insights or suggestions from the community. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: And what is *Your download logic*? how can we help you improve it if we don't know how the code looks like? for starters look at parallelism using multiple threads/processes.

Comment: 30 GB/s? Are your network and drive and the server that fast? And what is your current download time?

Comment: Not only the connection throughput need to be 30 GB/s as pointed out by KellyBundy, but the latency also needs to be very very small for the network to reach this speed (due to the way TCP works). The latency to remote web servers is generally often already few milliseconds (unless this is local servers or very close ones). Not to mention the SSL handcheck does not help on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach is to download images in parallel, like that

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

image_urls = ["https://example.com/image1.jpg", "https://example.com/image2.jpg"]
save_folder = "downloaded_images"

async def get(url, session, save_folder):
    try:
        async with session.get(url=url) as response:
            resp = await response.read()
            parsed = urlparse(url)
            destination = os.path.join(save_folder, os.path.basename(parsed.path))
            with open(destination, "w") as f:
                f.write(resp)
            print("Successfully got url {} with resp of length {}.".format(url, len(resp)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(url, e.__class__))


async def main(urls, save_folder):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get(url, session, save_folder) for url in urls])
    print("Finalized all. Return is a list of len {} outputs.".format(len(ret)))


start = time.time()
asyncio.run(main(image_urls, save_folder))
end = time.time()

print("Took {} seconds to pull {} images.".format(end - start, len(image_urls)))
```

Comment: i did this but it takes more time forn1image..

Comment: you can't optimize downloading process any better. Your expectations are too high. 30Mb/ms ~= 30Gb/s. Even if your channel is enough not every server can serve  static files at this speed.

Comment: How to increase speed of the website it takes for time for downloading health ecg reports images 5hours tims taken for downloading 1patience details only 1day details .how can i increase this speed with the code

Comment: I understand your question. But you don't understand the answer. You can't increase download speed by code optimization.